# How to use variable to get the value from an array object

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using below function to get the drop down populated in my application. I want to use that function globally in my application. the function i have used is,

```
function loadSelectOnRefresh( url, elementid, columnid, columnname, options ){
// declare default settings
var settings = $.extend({

    // default values
    iconClass: 'refreshIcon',
    onLoadIcon: baseUrl+"/ibuzz/images/refresh-ajax-loader.gif",
    afterLoadIcon: baseUrl+"/ibuzz/images/ajax-refresh-icon.gif"

}, options );

// loading effect
$('.'+settings.iconClass).attr('src',settings.onLoadIcon);

$.get(url,function(result){

    var selectOptions = '<option value="">Please Select</option>';
    var resultArr = $.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(resultArr, function(k, item) {
        selectOptions += '<option value="'+item[columnid]+'">'+item[columnname]+'</option>';
    });
    $('#'+elementid).html(selectOptions);
    $('.'+settings.iconClass).attr('src',settings.afterLoadIcon);

});}
```

The below code are in the above programming creating undefined...
Any body can help me to solve this.

```
   $.each(resultArr, function(k, item) {
        selectOptions += '<option value="'+item[columnid]+'">'+item[columnname]+'</option>';
    });
```

Comment: in your ajax reponse. before you do `$.parseJSON`, console.log and check what is in result variable.

Comment: Never mind, are you saying about the browser console log, right?